# Finding limit of integral

Tags: real-analysis, integration, limits, measure-theory, lebesgue-integral

> LEt $f:\Omega\to[0,\infty]$ measurable s.t $0<c:=\int_{\Omega}fd\mu<\infty$ . Prove that $$\lim_{n\to\infty}\int_{\Omega}n\log\bigg(1+\big(\frac f n\big)^a\bigg)d\mu=\cases{c\quad a=1\\\infty\quad 0<a<1\\0\quad 1<a<\infty}$$

About the first case, I got upper bound by $$\lim\int n\log(1+\frac f n)\le\lim\int n\log(\exp(\frac f n))=\int f=c$$ but on the other side I can get that $$\lim_{n\to\infty}\int_{\Omega}n\log\bigg(1+\big(\frac f n\big)^a\bigg)d\mu\ge\lim\int n\log(\frac f n)$$ and by L'hspital rule to get the limit on the RHS is equal to $\int f$ but on the other hand, I'm not sure I can apply it here.

Aout the other cases I'm clueless. I need a reasining for switiching the limit and the integral, i.e. does $\lim_{n\to\infty}\int_{\Omega}n\log\bigg(1+\big(\frac f n\big)^a\bigg)d\mu\overset{?}{=}\int_{\Omega}\lim_{n\to\infty}n\log\bigg(1+\big(\frac f n\big)^a\bigg)d\mu$?

How can I solve it for the other cases? Can I switch the limit and the integral as described?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can Switch the Limit and the integral.
For computing the Limit of the Integrand, use L'Hospitals rule.

$\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \frac{log(1+(\frac{f}{n})^a)}{\frac{1}{n}} = \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \frac{(log(1+(\frac{f}{n})^a))'}{(\frac{1}{n})'}$.

For deriving the numerator by $n$: $(log(1+(\frac{f}{n})^a))'=\frac{-af^a/n^{a+1}}{1+(\frac{f}{n})^a}$.

The above Quotient can be simplified and results in: $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \frac{af^a}{n^{a-1}+\frac{f^a}{n}}$.

Now consider the 3 different cases and take the Limit for every case.

Comment: Why can I switch the limit and the integral?

Comment: Because of the [dominated convergence theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dominated_convergence_theorem).

Comment: but $f_n$ is not bounded. Is it?

Comment: The integral is not bounded for $0<a<1$. For this case you must use other Lemmas like [Fatou's lemma](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fatou%27s_lemma#Reverse_Fatou_lemma)

Comment: Can you edit your answer with the correct lemmas and their use here please?

Comment: The Integrand is bounded for $a>1$. For this case I can use the dominated convergence Theorem that says that you can Switch Limit and integral. For the other case you are using the reverse Fatou Lemma.

Comment: Again, I can't see why it's bounded for $a>1$. About the others I think I understood, thanks.

Comment: To see why ist bounded for $a>1$ make a Taylor Expansion for the logarithm and you get a series in $(f/n)^a$.